# Permission denied when one script calls another

Tags: shell-script

I have a `sh` script that calles a `perl` script.

When I run the `perl` script it works, but when I run the `sh` script it fails to run the `perl` script complaning that

> `Permission denied`

Both scripts are `chmod a+rx` and the directories are `chmod a+rx`. Therefore this is wrong.

What is causing this?

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/sh

d=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

cd /home/rwb/thing
ls -l script*
pwd
script.pl

$ ./script.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 rwb rwb  5756 Feb 14 16:04 script.pl
/home/rwb/thing
./script.sh: 8: ./script.sh: script.pl: Permission denied
```

Comment: Are you sure that `script.pl` and `./script.pl` are the same thing? What is the content of you `$PATH` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`script.pl` or its parent directory don't appear in your `$PATH` variable.

You will therefore have to refer to it with the `./` prefix (the current working directory).

Change the line in your shell script from `script.pl` to `./script.pl`, or alternatively, provide the absolute path to your perl script.

Comment: That's it, thank you. Why _permission denied_ rather than _not found_?!